# SQL group by not working in inner join

Tags: sql

```
 string sqlString =
            "SELECT  task.idtask, SUM(task.hours), task.overtime, 
             task.taskdate, task.description, developers.iddevelopers, developers.developerfname, projects.idprojects, projects.ProjectName" +
            " FROM task" +
            " INNER JOIN developers ON developers.iddevelopers = task.iddevelopers" +
            " INNER JOIN projects ON projects.idprojects = task.idprojects"+
           "GROUP BY projects.ProjectName ";
```

how do i get the results in grouped order of the ProjectName

[the table at the moment without the group by](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1d4pv.jpg)

Comment: the query won't work as you failed to include the group by fields from the select fields which are not aggregated

Comment: could u explain that ? .. iv put the coloumn in the groupby in the select fields

Comment: @Senal Could you provide some sample data from those three tables and expect result? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @D-Shih iv added a screesnhot, i want the data to be shown grouped by the project name, DBMS is mysql

Comment: @Senal you probably misunderstood it,I mean you could provide some data from `task`,`developers`,`projects` tables and your expect result :)  you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have to include EVERY column in your select statement that is not an aggravate.

GROUP BY projects.ProjectName, task.idtask,task.overtime, 
             task.taskdate, task.description, developers.iddevelopers, developers.developerfname, projects.idprojects